# How to do efficent migration between oracle databases?

Tags: database, oracle, migration, data-migration

I was thinking about the most efficent solution for migration between two databases, both are Oracle. 
My idea is to use db-link, create functions and procedures to copy all data from one schema to other schema, I can not use Oracle Data pump because my new database has new schema so, Oracle Data pump is not usefull for me.
Do you know/try other ways to do it ?

Edit:
Tables has different names/column names. Structure of tables is different too.
Part of migration it will be used only once (around 10% of data) but second part will be use few times. Migration of 90% of data will be in downtime. Database contains more than 2 bilion rows.

Comment: Data pump can do various transformations. Do just mean a different schena; or do the tables have different names; or different structures too?

Comment: What does "migration" mean to you?  Is this a one-time operation?  Or an ongoing process?  Of how much data?  Online or during a downtime window?  Depending on the scope of the transforms, there are lots of ETL tools on the market (Oracle has a couple) but that might be overkill depending on what "migration" means to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If time permits and you do have Microsoft Visual Studio, you can look into SSIS packages to perform data migration by installing SSDT on Visual Studio. I've previously done similar DB migration, however, from Oracle DB to SQL Server.

You may also create separate SSIS packages to perform the different parts of migrations according to your needs.

Some references below to get you started.

[Microsoft SSIS Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx)

[DB migration using SSIS from DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25867/moving-data-from-one-db-to-another-using-ssis)